# SQL count columns of all tables in one database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to ask for help with a SQL command for counting columns of all tables in one database (NOT a sum of columns in ALL databases)

What is the situation:
db_a - 60 tables
db_b - 80 tables
db_c - 50 tables
db_d - 40 tables
...
...
information_schema

Problem is, that phpMyadmin or some SW I know like Navicat, does not show column count per table in list view, so I cannot even count it manualy without need to open table and there is maybe somewhere information about number of columns.

What I need is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE "database name is db_a";
```

but I cannot find a working WHERE part.

Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `TABLE_CATALOG`.  That is the database name in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`:

```
where TABLE_CATALOG = 'db_a'
```

Comment: this is exactly what is not working... under db_a it returns 0 even if it already has many tables. And yes, in my solution it is not db_a, but I have double checked the name of database

Comment: @Zorak . . . You might try using `lower()` (in case your database is collation sensitive).  Or there might be other arcane characters in the name that are confusing things.  You can check that using `like`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin with the obvious: Yes, this question is seven years old and the answer probably no longer relevant for the OP. On the other hand I just came across this while looking for a solution to find the number of columns per table for my database, so maybe this will help someone else later on.

This is what worked for me in the end:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME AS tbl, COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) AS cnt
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="db_1" GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
```